LTspice: photodiode current
I am working on building a circuit using the SG01D-5Lens (opamp: LMC6001) in LTspice, based on the values from the datasheet, in order to verify whether the theoretical values match the simulation results.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
However, since there is no diode library available, you have manually specified the values from the datasheet for the diode.

Is it acceptable to do this?

When comparing theoretical and simulation values, is it correct to compare Vout? According to the formula, I understand that
$$
V_\text{out} = -I_D \cdot R_1.
$$
From the equation, \$I_D = V_\text{cc} / R_\text{f}\$, so with a \$5\text{V}\$ supply and a \$10\text{G}\Omega\$ resistor, \$I_D\$ should be \$5\text{nA}\$. But the simulation result shows \$I_D = 2.5\text{pA}\$.

Is there something I might have overlooked to make the simulation match the theoretical values?




When you say "From the equation, ID = Vcc / Rf," what equation are you talking about? Where did you get "ID = Vcc / Rf"?

In the figure1 above, Ip.max is referred to as ID.
And since Up.max is Vcc , I understood the equation as follows. Did I misunderstand it?

If this circuit is working correctly, the output voltage should depend on the input optical power, not on Vcc at all.

Why is photocurrent ($I_P$) shown in the wrong direction in the first image?

@user453071 - Hi, Where did the 1st schematic come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

Oh! I didn't realize that. I have corrected it and deleted the document. Thank you!


From the equation, \$I_D = V_\text{cc} / R_\text{f}\$,

This is an equation for the maximum \$I_D\$ that the circuit can respond to linearly (assuming an op-amp with output that can go to the positive rail).
It doesn't predict the diode current for any particular illumination condition.

But the simulation result shows \$I_D = 2.5\text{pA}\$.

Is there something I might have overlooked to make the simulation match the theoretical values


You didn't include (as far as you've shared) any photocurrent --- that is, the current that the diode will conduct from cathode to anode when it is receiving optical energy.
The \$2.5\text{pA}\$ you see in the simulation is probably a leakage current of some kind.
Probably you want to include a current source in parallel with the diode in your model to represent the photocurrent. Set the current of the source according to whatever illumination conditions you want to simulate. For example you could ramp the photocurrent from \$0\$ to \$6\text{nA}\$ to see at what point the response becomes nonlinear.

Hello, thank you for your detailed explanation.
But I have a question.
Do I need to input a current source directly to represent the photocurrent, rather than setting it in the diode’s parameters? And, to simulate a photodiode, is it correct to typically observe the Vout  value with respect to the reverse voltage?

@user453071 without seeing the actual model file I don't know for sure. But if you want to, for example, see how the circuit reacts to an optical transient you're not going to be able to do that by setting a parameter.
RE " is it correct to typically observe the Vout value with respect to the reverse voltage?", that might be interesting for some reason in your application, but more often you're interested in how the circuit responds to changes in the optical input signal.

What you mean is that generating a current source and observing how much photocurrent flows in response to the input current is more important, right?

@user453071 No, I mean seeing how the rest of the circuit responds to the photocurrent is more important. The photodiode itself is pretty straightforward: photocurrent is proportional to optical signal. The things that can change that (how much of the optical beam falls on the active area of the PD? What's the optical spectrum of the beam? etc) aren't things an electrical simulator are going to be able to tell you anyway.


Do I need to input a current source directly to represent the photocurrent, rather than setting it in the diode’s parameters

Yes. The photocurrent is external to the diode. It is not the diode's "parameter" in any way. You could create a photodiode subcircuit that parallels a PN junction with a current source, and then you could parametrize the photocurrent, since you're then modelling both the photodiode and the light shining on it. You won't get that from the model of just a silicon diode.

in order to verify whether the theoretical values match the simulation results

I imagine that actually putting this together on a breadboard takes less time than writing the question. You really should just try the hardware if you can. It's the ultimate simulation you can get :)
Simulations have their uses, but if it's something this simple, just head to the bench. Of course it's good to learn how to model real hardware using SPICE, including transducers. It's your choice what's more important at given time though.
